# How to lazy load a wrapper div containing a carousel with images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I have a bunch of carousels each wrapped in `.lazy_wrap`. I would like to lazy load them to load the site faster. How would I approach this? I've looked at some lazy load plugins but they seem to only work on images. I found a plugin called [jquery-lazyloadanything](https://github.com/shrimpwagon/jquery-lazyloadanything) but I can't figure out how to use it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/667/

```html
<div class="lazy_wrap">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/668/

You need to add just this code:

```
$('img').lazyloadanything({
  'onLoad': function(e, LLobj) {
    var $img = LLobj.$element;
    var src = $img.attr('data-src');
    $img.attr('src', src);
    console.log("loading: ", src);
  }
});
```

But you don't want the images to get loaded "automatically", so you'll need to change `src="url"` to `data-src="url"` on each `img` tag, like:

```
<img data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
```

You'll also need to add height, width to the images either via the html tag or css, because lazyloadanything only loads them when it detects that they enter the screen but it can only happen when they have a size.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the loading to happen more dynamically? Like rather than having all of the images load at once, just have the relevant ones load as the user scrolls down. More like a traditional lazy load application.

Comment: If you change the html to have 15 different images instead of the same image 15 times :)

Comment: I tried putting it into my site, but none of the images load. I tested on the first carousel but all the images are empty except for one. http://imdarrien.com/

Comment: Open the javascript console, and fix the syntax error in your js

Comment: Ah opps! I uploaded to quickly. I fixed it but it still doesn't load.

Comment: You haven't change all " src"-s to " data-src" yet

Comment: I changed all the ones in the first carousel though. Shouldn't those load regardless of the other carousels?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102303/discussion-between-gavriel-and-user2252219).